# Flutter dio cache receives error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the dio_http_cache package for caching but I received an error that the object from JSON is null. Does anyone know any workaround for this?

```
E/flutter ( 6448): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 6448): #0      _$CacheObjFromJson (package:dio_http_cache/src/core/obj.g.dart:11:17)
E/flutter ( 6448): #1      new CacheObj.fromJson (package:dio_http_cache/src/core/obj.dart:43:7)
E/flutter ( 6448): #2      DiskCacheStore.getCacheObj (package:dio_http_cache/src/store/store_disk.dart:118:44)
E/flutter ( 6448): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6448): #3      CacheManager._pullFromCache (package:dio_http_cache/src/core/manager.dart:32:13)
E/flutter ( 6448): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6448): #4      CacheManager.pullFromCacheBeforeMaxAge (package:dio_http_cache/src/core/manager.dart:56:15)
E/flutter ( 6448): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6448): #5      DioCacheManager._onRequest (package:dio_http_cache/src/manager_dio.dart:48:33)
E/flutter ( 6448): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6448):
```